# I can't install any newer versions of vagrant past 1.8.1

Tags: apt, virtualbox, vagrant

I am using `apt-get` to install Vagrant on Ubuntu 16.04. The newest version listed on the website is 1.9.8, once installed I check the version and it is says I have 1.8.1 installed.

I then tried downloading the deb package and installing it that way but got the same result.

The reason I am trying to get a new version is because I am having problems with compatibility between Vagrant 1.8.1 and VirtualBox 5.1. I have found a work around but it is not ideal as we will be installing the same solution on many different machines.

How can I install vagrant 1.9.8 on Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: I don't see a problem ;-)  ... if you want 1.9.8 and there is no debian install file you install from source. And there is on on their website: https://www.vagrantup.com/downloads.html so what is the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> [How to upgrade to Vagrant 1.9.1 from any older version on Ubuntu
>   16.04](https://github.com/openebs/openebs/issues/32)
>
> **First remove the older version of vagrant.**
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove vagrant
> rm -r ~/.vagrant.d
> ```
>
> **Install instructions**
>
> ```
> wget https://releases.hashicorp.com/vagrant/1.9.1/vagrant_1.9.1_x86_64.deb
> sudo dpkg -i vagrant_1.9.1_x86_64.deb 
> vagrant version
> ```

Comment: I don't think I had been removing the old one properly beforehand. Thanks for your help!

Comment: the homestead upgrades over the past few years have been quite a mess, thank you for the helpful straight forward info here